# Цикл mysql

Tags: php, mysql

echo $утро?Доброе утро!:'';

у меня есть сотрудники список сотрудников, организованный как дерево, тоесть с подчиненностями (Parent_id).

Мне нужно вывести каждому сотруднику список задач для него и для его подчиненных
чрез PHP проблем нет, используя рекурсивные запросы, выбирая сотрудников, у которых Parent_id = Current_user_id, до тех пор пока mysql_num_rows !=0.

А может, такой перепросмотр можно организовать 1м SQL запросом. При условии, что я не знаю максимальную длину ветки дерева.

Answer (score 1):

Одним запросом можно в оракле, а в MySQL нужно свое городить, вот пример - http://club.shelek.ru/viewart.php?id=307#post_classic